# Not able to delete reminder in android studio

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite

I'm working on a pill reminder application using a database handler. The problem is that I'm not able to delete reminder and can't seem to find any errors. I'm very new to this still learning.

Here's my code for database handler:

```
 int deleteReminder(String name)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_REMINDERS,"medname" + "='" + name + "'",null);
    }
```

This is the java code:

```
 public void delete(View view) {

        DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        if (dh.deleteReminder(ar.get(0).toString()) > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, main.class);
            intent.putExtra("frag", "Med Reminder");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }
```

Xml:

```
  <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tint="#ffffff"
            android:onClick="delete"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
```